Loss of Internet Connection in Main Activity While Using Custom Tabs in Flutter on Android
I'm encountering an issue in my Flutter application where I lose internet connectivity in my main activity when a custom tab overlay (using the inappwebview package) is open in a second activity. The error log shows the following message:
W/Firestore( 8958): (25.1.0) [WatchStream]: (a5b7c53) Stream closed with status:Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com}

This connection issue persists only while the custom tab is open, and I regain internet access as soon as the custom tab is closed.

Flutter version: 3.24.3

Android version: 35.0.0

Device: Galaxy A35 5G, Galaxy A35 5G and Android-arm64 emulator

Packages used: inappwebview 6.1.4


I have checked my internet connection, and it works fine outside of this scenario.
The internet android permission is also present in the manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Does anyone have insights into why this might be happening or how I can resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated
